# AJAXPLORER (Pydio) inaccessible via LAN

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I am totally unable to access ajaxplorer through LAN. I am able to access it from the same pc. But, it is totally inaccessible from a different computer.

I can ping the machine however, nothing opens on the browser, even the apache default page is inaccessible.

Any idea as to what could be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though Apache isn't listening on your LAN-facing IP address.  Run

```
netstat -na | grep ':80.*LISTEN'
```

and look for a line that looks like either of

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.1:80          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

to show that Apache is listening.  Or, run `telnet 192.168.1.1 80` (if `192.168.1.1` is your LAN-facing IP address) and see if you can connect.

In Apache, do you have a `Listen 80` or `Listen 192.168.1.1:80` directive?

Comment: Yes I have a Listen 80 inside the ports.conf. I tried changing it to my.ip:80 too, but it had no effect

Comment: running the command you provided displays this : tcp  0  0 10.1.3.48:80  0.0.0.0:* LISTEN

Comment: And you're browsing to 10.1.3.48, or a host that resolves to that address?

Comment: I'm browsing through 10.1.3.48 from a different PC. Browsing to that ip from the same pc works, but does not work from a different PC on the LAN

Comment: Look, be a little more proactive here.  I'm trying to help you figure out if you can connect to your PC.  So does the telnet command I mentioned work?  Is there a firewall in the way?  Do other connections to that PC work?

Comment: I am sorry. I found the problem. It was the openstack firewall which blocked at a SWITCH LEVEL even though there was no firewall on the gateway.